# How to properly handle changed attributes in a Rails before_save hook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class StopWord < ActiveRecord::Base
  UPDATE_KEYWORDS_BATCH_SIZE = 1000

  before_save :update_keywords

  def update_keywords
    offset = 0
    max_id = ((max_kw = Keyword.first(:order => 'id DESC')) and max_kw.id) || 0
    while offset <= max_id
      begin
        conditions = ['id >= ? AND id < ? AND language = ? AND keyword RLIKE ?',
            offset, offset + UPDATE_KEYWORDS_BATCH_SIZE, language]

        # Clear keywords that matched the old stop word
        if @changed_attributes and (old_stop_word = @changed_attributes['stop_word']) and not @new_record
          Keyword.update_all 'stopword = 0', conditions + [old_stop_word]
        end

        Keyword.update_all 'stopword = 1', conditions + [stop_word]

      rescue Exception => e
        logger.error "Skipping batch of #{UPDATE_KEYWORDS_BATCH_SIZE} keywords at offset #{offset}"
        logger.error "#{e.message}: #{e.backtrace.join "\n    "}"

      ensure
        offset += UPDATE_KEYWORDS_BATCH_SIZE
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This works just fine, as the unit tests show:

```
class KeywordStopWordTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def test_stop_word_applied_on_create
    kw = Factory.create :keyword, :keyword => 'foo bar baz', :language => 'en'
    assert !kw.stopword, 'keyword is not a stop word by default'

    sw = Factory.create :stop_word, :stop_word => kw.keyword.split(' ')[1], :language => kw.language
    kw.reload
    assert kw.stopword, 'keyword is a stop word'
  end

  def test_stop_word_applied_on_save
    kw = Factory.create :keyword, :keyword => 'foo bar baz', :language => 'en', :stopword => true
    sw = Factory.create :keyword_stop_word, :stop_word => kw.keyword.split(' ')[1], :language => kw.language

    sw.stop_word = 'blah'
    sw.save

    kw.reload
    assert !kw.stopword, 'keyword is not a stop word'
  end
end
```

But mucking with the `@changed_attributes` instance variable just feels wrong. Is there a standard Rails-y way to get the old value of an attribute that is being modified on a save?

**Update:** Thanks to [Douglas F Shearer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13831/douglas-f-shearer) and [Simone Carletti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123527/simone-carletti) (who apparently prefers Murphy's to Guinness), I have a cleaner solution:

```
  def update_keywords
    offset = 0
    max_id = ((max_kw = Keyword.first(:order => 'id DESC')) and max_kw.id) || 0
    while offset <= max_id
      begin
        conditions = ['id >= ? AND id < ? AND language = ? AND keyword RLIKE ?',
            offset, offset + UPDATE_KEYWORDS_BATCH_SIZE, language]

        # Clear keywords that matched the old stop word
        if stop_word_changed? and not @new_record
          Keyword.update_all 'stopword = 0', conditions + [stop_word_was]
        end

        Keyword.update_all 'stopword = 1', conditions + [stop_word]

      rescue StandardError => e
        logger.error "Skipping batch of #{UPDATE_KEYWORDS_BATCH_SIZE} keywords at offset #{offset}"
        logger.error "#{e.message}: #{e.backtrace.join "\n    "}"

      ensure
        offset += UPDATE_KEYWORDS_BATCH_SIZE
      end
    end
  end
```

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want `ActiveModel::Dirty`.

Examples:

```
person = Person.find_by_name('Uncle Bob')
person.changed?       # => false

person.name = 'Bob'
person.changed?       # => true
person.name_changed?  # => true
person.name_was       # => 'Uncle Bob'
person.name_change    # => ['Uncle Bob', 'Bob']
```

Full documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Comment: The documentation says you need to `include` the module, and then a few more steps, but you don't need to - you can just call the methods as written down by [Douglas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/13831/douglas-f-shearer)

Comment: quite interesting; some details young won't think are available at first. But it seems to works without including anything

Answer (score 1):

You're using the right feature but the wrong API.
You should `#changes` and `#changed?`.

See [this article](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/31/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-dirty-objects) and the [official API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).

Two additional notes about your code:

1. Never rescue Exception directly when you actually want to rescue execution errors. This is Java-style. You should rescue StandardError instead because lower errors are normally compilation error or system error.
2. You don't need the begin block in this case.

   ```
   def update_keywords
     ...
     rescue => e
     ...
     ensure
     ...
   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the note on exception handling. I'm now just rescuing StandardError. It seems that I do need the begin block, however. `while ... rescue ... ensure ... end` does not work for me. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I didn't see the begin/rescue/end block was inside the while. In this case you need the begin. Sorry.